# How to show two pieces of data in one row depend on id in rdlc reporting

Tags: c#, sql, .net, reporting-services, rdlc

[image]

[image: rdlc report]

Blue is one employee name and red is another employee name. Here showing two rows but I want one row. I'm using

```
=Fields!EmpName.Value & Fields!LeaveDate.Value
```

expression how to show two rows of data into one row. That means blue row contains two leave types in one row

Used each row `=Fields!EmpName.Value & Fields!LeaveDate.Value` expression

```
CREATE PROCEDURE query
        (@EmployeeIds varchar(8000),       
         @TenantId int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @empIds TABLE (id int);

    INSERT INTO @empIds 
        SELECT Id 
        FROM SplitStringToIntRows(@EmployeeIds, ','); 

    SELECT 
        et.LeaveDate AS LeaveDate, lt.Value AS LeaveType,
        emp.FirstName + ' ' + emp.LastName AS EmpName,
        emp.CustomEmployeeId AS CustomEmployeeId,
        CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS StartDate,
        DATEADD(month, 1, CONVERT (date, GETDATE())) AS EndDate
    FROM 
        LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction et
    INNER JOIN 
        LeaveManagement.LeaveMaster lm ON et.LeaveMasterId = lm.LeaveMasterId 
    INNER JOIN 
        Lookup.LeaveType lt ON lt.LeaveTypeId = lm.LeaveTypeId
    INNER JOIN 
        HumanResource.Employee emp ON emp.EmployeeId = et.EmployeeId
    INNER JOIN 
        @empIds empPar ON empPar.id = et.EmployeeId 
    WHERE
        CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(et.LeaveDate AS DATE), 110) >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(et.LeaveDate AS DATE), 110) <= DATEADD(month, 1, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
        AND emp.TenantId = @TenantId
        --AND lt.Value='No Pay Leave'
END
```

[image]

Comment: please include all relevant code

Comment: could you also add your sql query?

Comment: Can you show the query result in table format as if you are running it on the database so that it will be easier for us. Also, can you make a sample desired output (doesn't need to be very clean but understandable)?

Comment: John Ephraim Tugado I'm posted SQL table output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add EmpName field into your row groups. e.g. in below image i have grouped my data in HRIM field that i had.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you must add "Fields!EmpName.Value "  in the Group expressions of the row groups.